Why is (I+A) invertible and what is its inverse?
Let A and B be n x n (square) matrices where A^2 = 0 and B^2 = 0.
Let I be the identity matrix.
(I+A) is invertible. Why? What is its inverse?
Does A^2 = 0 imply that the matrix A is nilpotent, making it non invertible?
Just trying to make sense of this situation.

What does $B$ have to do with anything?  Also, $I^2-A^2 = (I+A)(I-A)$.

$A^2 = 0$ does imply that the matrix $A$ is nilpotent. It also clearly has determinant $0$.  It is non-invertible.

If $A^2=0$, then $A$ does not have $-1$ as an eigenvalue. Therefore, $A+I$ does not have $0$ as an eigenvalue.

Under some conditions on a real number $x,$  we have
$$ \frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - ...  $$
Note that any power of a square matrix $A$  commutes with any other power. And
Under some conditions on a square  matrix $A,$  we have
$$ (I+A)^{-1} = I - A + A^2 - A^3 + A^4 - ...  $$
The usual condition involves convergence of the infinite sum. In your case, it is not infinite, the sum "converges" and the equation is just true.
